# Second Degree Connection in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been tasked with finding the number of second degree connections of a 'contactee' in a table 'contacts' with columns 'contactee' and 'contacter'. So far I have been able to find the names of the second degree contacts but not eliminate those that are first degree contacts. For example if Adam is both a second degree connection and first degree connection of Mike, the query should not return Adam, but my query does.  I am new to SQL so any help is great.

```
SELECT 
  contactsB.contacter
FROM 
  contacts AS contactsB
  INNER JOIN contacts AS contactsA 
  ON contactsA.contacter = contactsB.contactee 
    AND contactsA.contactee <> contactsB.contactee 
    AND contactsA.contactee = <insert contactee here>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the table schema, some sample data and expected output for a better chance to answer it

Comment: Do you expect `Mike` and `mike` to be two different contacts?

Comment: No i'm sorry that was just a typo. Thanks for being patient and your help!

Comment: No worries, does this do your job? `SELECT b.contactee, c.contacter FROM contacts b INNER JOIN contacts c ON b.contacter = c.contactee AND b.contactee != c.contacter ORDER BY 1`

Comment: Yes, but it still returns 'ben' which I don't want since he is a first degree connection of mike. Do you know how to get rid of the first degree contacts, in essence immediate contactee-contacter relationships? I tried NOT IN and EXCEPT functions but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how to return the number of connections rather than the names? Like for mike it would return 1 since thats the number of second degree connections vs the name 'chris'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91820/discussion-between-mynawaz-and-user2484406).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT b.contactee, c.contacter 
FROM 
    contacts b 
    INNER JOIN contacts c ON b.contacter = c.contactee AND b.contactee != c.contacter 
ORDER BY 1
```

To get number of second degree contacts, just add `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` this way

```
SELECT b.contactee, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    contacts b 
    INNER JOIN contacts c ON b.contacter = c.contactee AND b.contactee != c.contacter 
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.contacter, b.contactee 
FROM
    contacts a INNER JOIN contacts b
    ON a.contacter = b.contactee
    AND a.contactee != b.contacter 
    AND b.contacter NOT IN 
        (SELECT c.contacter 
         FROM 
             contacts c 
             WHERE a.contactee = c.contactee)
ORDER BY 1
```